# Python dictionary arrays within

Tags: python, dictionary

was wondering if it was possible to have a value with multiple keys and vice versa in a python dictionary. I am a beginner so i am assuming this should be an easy solve, just need the correct formatting.

Was looking for something like this:

```
   dictionary = {
                '1','2','3': "blue"
                '4': "blue","green"
                }
```

Comment: Presumably you're looking for `dictionary['1'] == dictionary['2'] == dictionary['3']`? Then no, there's no shorthand for that.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? It's probably better to talk about what exact use you're trying to achieve, because as described this is neither possible nor sensible.

Comment: No, the numbers are representing keys in the dictionary and the colors are values. Was wondering if there was an easier way to assign the same value to different keys instead of doing                                                                            { '1': "blue",                                                                                                                           '2':"blue,                                                                                                                               '3':'blue}      and instead do something like { '1','2','3':"blue"}

Comment: You definitely can't have multiple values for a key, that defeats the point of a dictionary. You can, on the other hand, have a list as a value, which might suit your needs.

Comment: You can switch the keys and values and have a list of something mapped by a key. But you cannot have multiple values for keys

Comment: Then no, as I said above, there's no shorthand. You could try `dict.fromkeys('123', 'blue')`, but that won't allow you to provide any keys with non-`'blue'` values and will likely surprise you with mutable values.

Answer (score 3):

`dict` can only have one value/name for one key :

```
>>> dic={}
>>> dic['1']=12
>>> dic
{'1': 12}
```

other way it create a tuple as `key` :

```
>>> dic={}
>>> dic['1','2']=12
>>> dic
{('1', '2'): 12}
```

a dictionary is one key that can contain what ever you want, but in your example if value are key and colors values, you should have `dic={1: ['blue'], 2: ['blue'], 3: ['blue'], 4: ['blue', 'green']}`:

but you can built it in a shorter way.

one option :

```
>>> dic={i:["blue"] for i in [1,2,3]}
>>> dic[4]=["blue", "green"]
>>> dic
{1: ['blue'], 2: ['blue'], 3: ['blue'], 4: ['blue', 'green']}
```